# \scriptstyle placement fine tuning

Tags: symbols, fontsize, math-operators

I need a functional composition operator. I find `\circ` too big for it, so I've declared a math operator (within the amsart documentclass) as `\scriptstyle\circ` instead; the size is exactly what I would like to have but the placement seems wrong now, it is too low.

[image]

Does anybody know a simple way (without too many `\raise`s and `box`es) to place the symbol slightly higher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with defining a new command `\smallcirc`

```
\newcommand{\smallcirc}{\mathbin{\text{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\scalebox{0.6}{$\circ$}}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\smallcirc}{\mathbin{\text{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\scalebox{0.6}{$\circ$}}}}}

\begin{document}
\[
 f\circ\alpha \quad\text{vs}\quad f\smallcirc\alpha
\]

\[
 f \smallcirc \alpha_{f \smallcirc \alpha_{f \smallcirc \alpha}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, defining the command with a `\scripstyle` in it, it's not a good idea since if you have that symbol in a sub/superscript, its size will remain the same as the one in display style.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I preferred this one since it is more concise, more customizable, and works without `graphicx` too :D

Comment: Oops maybe it still needs `graphicx` - I load `tikz` and that I think loads `graphicx`... Well anyway

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You're welcome. And, yes, `tikz` loads `graphicx`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer that will work even in sub/superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\centeredcirc}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1\circ$}}}
\newcommand{\smallcirc}{\mathbin{\mathchoice{\centeredcirc\scriptstyle}{\centeredcirc\scriptstyle}{\centeredcirc\scriptscriptstyle}{\centeredcirc\scriptscriptstyle}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ f\circ\alpha \quad\text{vs}\quad f\smallcirc\alpha \]
    \[ g^{f\circ\alpha} \quad\text{vs}\quad g^{f\smallcirc\alpha} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yours is a useful answer, I accepted another one since there I could fine-tune the position more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses the scaling method of karlkoeller's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233949/16967) and enhances it in several ways:

- The new symbol is correctly vertically centered around the math axis.
- The side bearings are restored (heuristic).
- The scaling diminishes the line width. This is compensated by additionally stroking the symbol with an estimated line width to compensate the scaling.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\smallcirc}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@smallcirc{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\smallcircscale}{.6}
\newcommand*{\@smallcirc}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}% \ht0: math axis
  \sbox2{$#1\circ\m@th$}%
  % Calculate symbol width with original side bearings
  % (in the hope, the symbol height is correct).
  % The radius is estimated as symbol height minus math axis
  % (\ht2 - \ht0).
  \dimen@=\dimexpr
    \smallcircscale\dimexpr2\ht2-2\ht0\relax
    + \wd2-2\ht2+2\ht0
  \relax
  % Estimated line thickness from symbol height
  \dimen2=.1\ht2
  % Calculate line width for rendering mode "Stroke".
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\dimen2 - \smallcircscale\dimen2\relax
  \raise\ht0\hbox to \dimen@{%
    \hfil
    \textpdfrender{
      TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
      LineWidth=\dimen2,
    }{%
      \scalebox{\smallcircscale}{%
        \lower\ht0\hbox{%
          $#1\circ\m@th$%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \hfil
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \text{styles: }&
  f \smallcirc \alpha \quad
  \scriptstyle f \smallcirc \alpha \quad
  \scriptscriptstyle f \smallcirc \alpha
\\
  \text{{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont\textbackslash circ}: }&
  f \circ \alpha \quad
  \scriptstyle f \circ \alpha \quad
  \scriptscriptstyle f \circ \alpha
\\
  \text{axis: }&
  \sbox0{${-}{\smallcirc}{-}$}
  \rlap{\copy0}%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{%
      \textcolor{red}{%
        \vrule width\wd0 height .05pt depth .05pt\relax
      }%
    }%
  }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]